# Quadratic Bezier Curve: Calculate x for any given y

Tags: javascript, bezier, quadratic

I have a quadratic bezier curve represented by the following equation (replaced t with x) where x is between 0-1

```
var y = p0 * Math.pow(x, 2) + p1 * 2 * x * (1 - x) + p2 * Math.pow((1 - x), 2)
```

I want to pass in a known y value and solve for x along the curve.

### [image]

I tried rearranging the quadratic to solve for x, but neither value I get falls within the 0-1 range.

Comment: What are the values of `p0`, `p1` and `p2`?

Comment: p0 = (0, 0); p1=(0.5, 450); p2= (1, 700);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
y = p0 * Math.pow(x, 2) + p1 * 2 * x * (1 - x) + p2 * Math.pow((1 - x), 2)

=> y = p0x^2 + 2p1(x-x^2) + p2(1-2x+x^2)
=> y = p0x2 + 2p1x - 2p1x2 +p2 - 2p2x + p2x2
=> y = p0x2 + p2x2  - 2p1x2 + 2p1x - 2p2x + p2
=> y = (p0+p2-2p1)x^2 + 2(p1 - p2)x + p2
=> 0 = (p0+p2-2p1)x^2 + 2(p1 - p2)x + (p2 - y)
```

This is simple Quadratic equation solve it further by entering p0, p1 , p2 and y you will get an equation for x..
x will two answer always .. discard negtive one postive answer will be your answer

Comment: It should be (p2 - y) in the last equation.

Comment: Thanks #fang missed that now coreccted

Comment: Thanks this ended up working:
(-(2 * p1 - 2 * p2) +- Math.sqrt(Math.pow(2 * p1 - 2 * p2, 2) - 4 * (p0 + p2 - 2 * p1) * (p2 - y))) / (2 * ((p0 + p2 - 2 * p1)))